# how to execute mysql raw query in drupal

Tags: drupal, sum, subquery

```sql
SELECT SUM(visits) AS totalvisits 
FROM (SELECT visits FROM dip_website_visits WHERE nid=20339 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 12) AS T
```

How to convert this SQL query to Drupal query? Can we use `db_query` for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to Drupal query like this:

```php
$subquery = \Drupal::database()->select('dip_website_visits');
$subquery->addField('dip_website_visits', 'visits');
$subquery->condition('nid', 20339);
$subquery->orderBy('date', 'desc');
$subquery->range(0, 12);

$query = \Drupal::database()->select($subquery);
$query->addExpression('sum(visits)', 'totalvisits');

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: dear sum aggregate function disregarding range..it calucating all records sum

Comment: @user1280660 that was my mistake. I have updated my answer